# How to extend express.js session

Tags: session, node.js, express

How can I make sure a session for a client on my express.js app lasts longer than a few hours? I don't want them to log in anew every time they visit my site.

I tried to fiddle with the `expires` option on the `express.session` method, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: If doesn't have any effects you should create an issue in github repo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `req.session.cookie.expires = aSpecificDateAndTime;` or `req.session.cookie.maxAge = aNumberOfMilliseconds;`. Both are equivalent, according to [the docs](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-session.html).

Forgot to mention, you can also set these options when setting the middleware (i.e. `express.session({secret: "whatever", cookie: {maxAge: 60000}});`

Answer (score 0):

```
cookie: {
    path: '/'
    ,expires: false
    ,httpOnly: true
    ,domain:'.example.com'
}
```

Above setting gives you to have session alive until browser closes.

Available among all pages ( path set to root ).